# What is the meaning of the output MonoJust for tests result in Spock

Tags: groovy, spring-webflux, spock

I have written some tests that in spock that give me results I can't make sense of. When I try to assert in the then: block the test fails with the output of MonoJust. I have no idea what that means. Can someone please explain why this is happening? When I print result, I just get the output MonoJust as well.

Here is the code:

```java
    def "should retrieve product by its  productId "() {
        given:

        def product = builder.createProduct()
        1 * producteService.findProduct(product.group, PRODUCT_ID) >> Mono.just(product)

        when:
        def result = controller.getBranch(product.group, PRODUCT_ID)

        then:
               StepVerifier.create(result)
                .expectNext(product-> {
                   assertThat(product.getProductId()).isEqualTo(PRODUCT_ID)
                }
                .expectComplete().verify()

    }
```

Unfortunately, I get this error which makes no sense to me:

```java
    Condition failed with Exception:

StepVerifier.create(result) .expectNext(product -> { assertThat(product.getProductId()).isEqualTo(PRODUCT_ID) }) .expectComplete().verify()
|            |      |        |                                                                                |                |
|            |      MonoJust |                                                                                |                java.lang.AssertionError: expectation "expectNext
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a red-herring and part of Spock's [implicit assertions](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.3/all_in_one.html#_conditions), which doesn't mesh well with fluent assertion utils.

You can get less confusing readouts by splitting it like this:

```
    def "should retrieve product by its  productId "() {
        given:
        def product = builder.createProduct()

        when:
        def result = controller.getBranch(product.group, PRODUCT_ID)

        then:
        1 * producteService.findProduct(product.group, PRODUCT_ID) >> Mono.just(product)

        and:
        def verifier = StepVerifier.create(result)
                .expectNext(product-> {
                   assertThat(product.getProductId()).isEqualTo(PRODUCT_ID)
                }
                .expectComplete()
        verifier.verify() 

    }
```

Also note that mock assertions belong in the `then` block.

The actual error was:
`java.lang.AssertionError: expectation "expectNext`, i.e., you didn't get a result.

Comment: Thinking about it, it might be that you need to move the `verify()` call in the then block, as that triggers the execution, otherwise the mock will probably complain. But I can't verify this as this example is not runnable.

Comment: Thank you Leonard, really appreciated and thank you for the explanation as well